# How to determine the correct end of a range function in Python?

Tags: python

I noticed that I get the exact same results when I am trying to do this, for example:

```
   range(1,13,2)
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

And

```
   range(1,12,2)
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

The result is the exact same, but which one would be correct in this case and why?

Does the end of a range have to do something with the steps you take?

> Like, the idea that a list should give me 11 as the last number, so I
>   should take 13 because we have a step of 2, or is this a bad thought?

Comment: If they both produce the output you desire, then they are both correct. As long as you understand what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks, Cory. I really don't understand why a question like this is being downvoted. Downvoters: please explain to me WHY you vote it down. Damn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), if `step` is strictly positive, the largest element in the range will be the largest `start + i * step` less than `stop`.

It means that the largest element is:

```
start + ((stop - start - 1)//step) * step
```

The result is the same for `range(1,13,2)` and `range(1,12,2)` (11) because of the integer division:

```
>>> 11 // 2
5
>>> 10 // 2
5
```

To avoid any surprise, you could always use `max + 1` as `stop`. For your example, that'd be `range(1,12,2)`.

Comment: Max, meaning 11 here?

Comment: @Siyah: Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. A range is a sequence of number starting at start spaced by step and strictly lesser than stop. Because of that definition, you will find always step possible values for stop giving exact same sequence (special case: when step has the default value 1, only one single value exists for stop)

Comment: Thanks, Serge. Which one would you use, yourself? I want to know how the pros do it.

Comment: @Siyah: the one that comes more natural in your use case. If you want the numbers to be lesser than 12 use 12, if your actual limit should be 13 use 13.

Answer (score 0):

```
range(start,end,step)
```

The range function will give you numbers starting at "start" until it reaches "end-1", but each number will have a distance to the next with length "step".

for your first case your end is 13-1 = 12, so the final value you can get is 12. But since your step is 2 it gets to 11 (1,3,5,7,9), adds 2 and gets 13, which it can't go to.

For you second case your end is 12-1=11. It adds 2 until it reaches 11 (1,3,5,7,9) and stops there.

There isn't really a right answers to which one you are supposed to use as it will depend on what you are using range for. I guess there will be slightly less calculation going on for your case two as it doesn't have to add the final step, but that is minor.